# Apply theme to a single view

Tags: android, android-theme

I need to apply a theme to a button irrespective of the Application theme (programmatically or in xml). The resources I found were basically pointing me to use `ContextThemeWrapper` the problem with that is I could not find a good example of doing it correctly

my xml has

```
<LinearLayout>
<TextView> <!-- Should follow the current theme !>
<Button> <!-- Needs to be irrespective of the theme; I need to put in the Light theme here always>
</LinearLayout>
```

in my onCreate I have

```
LayoutInflater to inflate
getLayoutInflater().inflate .. 
TextVIew t = view.findViewById(txt);
// How do I change this theme from code or XML 
Button b = view.findViewById(but);
```

I need to apply a theme; style won't do.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<Button
    style="@style/MyStyle">
```

It should be enough.

Comment: I cant do that the style is basically overriden by my application theme. I have multiple styles based on the theme